# Calling virtual method of a derived class causes segfaults

Tags: c++, pointers, derived-class

I'm trying to make a chess program, but I want to be able to implement different AIs in it. Thus I made a abstract AIgeneric class and the derived class AIrandom off of AIgeneric. Then in my chessAI interface, I create a list of the the AIs, and try to call their getNextMove function and run into a segfault. The code is as below:

```
class AIgeneric {
    public:
        virtual int getNextMove(int*, const int &) = 0;
}

class AIrandom : public AIgeneric {
    public:
        AIrandom();
        virtual int getNextMove(int*, const int &);
}


class chessAI {
    public:
        chessAI();
        ~chessAI();
        void setAI();
        int getNextMove(int*, const int &); 
    private:
        vector<AIgeneric*> AIlist;
        vector<string> names;
        int selectedAI;
};


chessAI::chessAI () {
    AIrandom randomAI;
    AIlist.push_back(&randomAI);
    names.push_back("Random AI");
    selectedAI = -1;
}

int chessAI::getNextMove(int * board, const int & color) {
    return AIlist[selectedAI]->getNextMove(board, color); //segfault on this line
}
```

It'd be great if anyone could help me on this problem!

Edit: I do set selectedAI to 0 before calling getNextMove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
chessAI::chessAI () {
    AIrandom randomAI;
    AIlist.push_back(&randomAI);
    names.push_back("Random AI");
    selectedAI = -1;
}
```

You store a pointer to a local variable into your vector. After the constructor returns that pointer is no longer valid.

Remember that all local variables are stored on the stack, and the stack is reused in other functions. So when you use the pointer in the vector, it now points to some other functions memory and not the one object you declared.

This can be solved in three ways:

1. Allocate the object on the heap:

   ```
   AIlist.push_back(new AIRandom);
   ```
2. Not using pointers at all.
3. Use smart pointers, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Answer (score 1):

You call `selectedAI = -1;` and then `AIlist[selectedAI]->...`. What do you expect `AIlist[-1]` to be, other than undefined behavior?

Comment: Sorry, between that time I do all setAI() which prompts the user to enter a number, and I made sure that selectedAI was 0 at the moment of calling

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is because `AIlist[selectedAI]` is out of bounds. You can confirm this by replacing it with `AIlist.at(selectedAI)`. Keep in mind that this index is -1 immediately after the constructor...